# applying a css class to every instance of an echoed php variable

Tags: php, css, variable-assignment

I would like to apply a css class (.error) to every echoed instance of `$error`. It seems like an easy thing to do, I'm just not sure about the syntax.

```
<?php // rclogin.php
    include_once 'rcheader.php';
    echo "<h3>Member Log in</h3>";
    $error = $user = $pass = "";

    if (isset($_POST['user']))
    {
        $user = sanitizeString($_POST['user']);
        $pass = sanitizeString($_POST['pass']);

        if ($user == "" || $pass == "")
        {
            $error = "Not all fields were entered<br />";
        }
        else
        {
            $query = "SELECT user,pass FROM rcmembers
                      WHERE user='$user' AND pass='$pass'";

            if (mysql_num_rows(queryMysql($query)) == 0)
            {
                $error = "Username/Password invalid<br />";
            }
```

Comment: Your code does not contain the `error` class anywhere. Into which concrete problem did you run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all - do not put into `$error` a whole HTML. It's a bad habbit in my opinion. Place there just an error info:

```
$error = 'Not all fields were entered';
```

And then in HTML during printing error info:

```
if ( $error ) {
    echo '<span class="error">' . $error . '</span><br/>';
}
```

As you can see - if you pass HTML in variables, you have less opportunities to do everything you want.

Answer (score 2):

To suggest something slightly different, I like to implement my errors as a class.

Now as it's a class, I can use the `__toString()` magic method.

```
class Error
{
    ...

    public function __toString()
    {
        ...
        $output = '<span class="error">' . $output . '</span>';
        return $output;
    }
}

$error = new Error;
```

Now when you echo $error, you can specify some HTML to be applied around the message, and as its a class, you can contain all of your other related error functions together in a nice object.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible depending on how you want to do it.

You could have something like this `$error = "<span class='className'>Username/Password invalid</span>";`

or you could first create the error variable with `$error = "<span class='className'>"` and end it with `$error .= "</span>"`